# Probability question in textbook

Tags: probability

"In the game of craps, a player rolls two dice. They win at once if the total is 7 or 11, and lose at once if the total is 2, 3, or 12. Otherwise, they continue rolling the dice until they either win by throwing their initial total again, or lose by rolling 7.
Show that the probability they win is 0.493."

I used this to calculate the probability:

$$P(4)\frac{P(4)}{P(4)+P(7)}+P(5)\frac{P(5)}{P(5)+P(7)}+P(6)\frac{P(6)}{P(6)+P(7)}+P(7)+P(8)\frac{P(8)}{P(8)+P(7)}$$
$$+P(9)\frac{P(9)}{P(9)+P(7)}+P(10)\frac{P(10)}{P(10)+P(7)}+P(11)$$

where $P(k)$ denotes the probability of getting a sum of $k$ with one throw of the two dice.

Somehow, though, this is wrong (doesn't give the right answer). Why?

Comment: Direct answer to the question: they're allowed to get more than two rolls: it looks like your calculation implicitly assumes that the second roll is definitely either going to be a seven or the same as the first roll.

Comment: Isn't the probability of $A$ happening before $B$ does, when the thing is repeated indefinitely until one of $A$ or $B$ happens, $\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$?

Comment: @EricStucky: I think the argument is correct. What is needed is just $P(A|A \cup B)$. Or we can write out the expression completely. Say we have $3$ disjoint possibilities $A$ (win), $B$ (lose) and $C$ (re-throw). Probability of winning is $P(A) + P(C)P(A) + [P(C)]^2P(A) + \ldots = \frac{P(A)}{1-P(C)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$.

Comment: @EricDong: The expression looks correct and it is evaluating to the required probability. Can you check your calculations again?

Comment: I agree with polkjh's assertion that the expression looks correct. The answer is supposed to be $\frac{244}{495}=0.49292929\cdots$. Are you getting something different? A [detailed statement](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/sp2005/homework/PS08.pdf) of the game and [complete solution](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/sp2005/homework/HW08.pdf) are available on-line.

Comment: The answer given in the textbook is 0.493.

Comment: Are these probabilities for dice sums correct?

$P(2)=1/36$

$P(3)=1/18$

$P(4)=1/12$

$P(5)=1/9$

$P(6)=5/36$
$P(7)=1/6$
$P(8)=5/36$
$P(9)=1/9$
$P(10)=1/12$
$P(11)=1/18$
$P(12)=1/36$

Comment: Yes, they are correct. But it might be better to express all fractions with a denominator of $36$ in which case perhaps you will see an even more interesting version of the palindrome that is visible in your calculations.

Comment: @EricDong $0.493$ versus $0.49292929\cdots$. Perhaps rounding off to three significant digits?

Comment: I got 0.45 something something. Probably a mistake with my stackless old calculator lol

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in the textbook. It should say that the probability is *approximately* $0.493$. Your calculations are correct.